# Wifi usb adapter atheros 9170 chipset not working on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: wireless, drivers, usb, atheros

I'm new to Ubuntu and Linux.
Have just changed my OS from Windows 7 to Ubuntu.
I'm running a HP/Compaq 6910p laptop.
My Icidu 300N 802.11n adapter stopped to work. It contains a atheros AR9170 chipset.

I have read many answers in this and other forums but none of them quite gave me the answers.

Can anyone out there give me some good advice??

`lshw` shows:

```
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82566MM Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 03
       serial: 00:1b:38:eb:45:38
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=2.1.4-k duplex=full firmware=0.3-0 ip=192.168.0.122 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:43 memory:e4620000-e463ffff memory:e4640000-e4640fff ioport:4060(size=32)


  *-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       product: PRO/Wireless 4965 AG or AGN [Kedron] Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:10:00.0
       logical name: wlan1
       version: 61
       serial: 00:1d:e0:67:f5:3b
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwl4965 driverversion=3.8.0-30-generic firmware=228.61.2.24 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
       resources: irq:48 memory:e4000000-e4001fff


  *-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@2:1
       logical name: wlan0
       serial: 6c:fd:b9:07:0e:c7
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=carl9170 driverversion=3.8.0-30-generic firmware=1.9.6 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
```

`lsusb` shows:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0cf3:1002 Atheros Communications, Inc. TP-Link TL-WN821N v2 802.11n [Atheros AR9170]
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Comment: I notice both the internal Intel card and the USB Atheros show as disabled. Some laptops will disable all wireless including USB if the wireless switch is off. What does this tell us? rfkill list all

Comment: Here is the result of rfkill: 0: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: yes
1: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: yes
2: hp-bluetooth: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: yes

Comment: It appears that the wireless switch is set to disable wireless. Please move the switch or press the key combination.

Comment: The built in is turned of, but my adapter is via usb, which i prefer. So my main problem....i think is usb socket???... 
Btw took a new copy of rfkill 
0: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: yes
2: hp-bluetooth: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
4: phy1: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no

Comment: Are there any clues? dmesg | grep -e carl -e wlan0

Comment: That command doesn't work. No response.

Comment: Let's try to provoke a useful response: sudo modprobe carl9170 and then:  dmesg | grep -e carl -e wlan0

Comment: Now this output: [ 5479.761854] usbcore: registered new interface driver carl9170
lsusb returned:
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0cf3:1002 Atheros Communications, Inc. TP-Link TL-WN821N v2 802.11n [Atheros AR9170]
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 03f0:171d Hewlett-Packard Bluetooth 2.0 Interface [Broadcom BCM2045]
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus etc.

Comment: lshw shows:
 *-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@2:1
       logical name: wlan0
       serial: 6c:fd:b9:07:0e:c7
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=carl9170 driverversion=3.8.0-30-generic firmware=1.9.6 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn

Answer (score 0):

I am quite suspicious that the wireless switch or key combination is at fault here. Please see:

> *-network DISABLED

Let's blacklist the driver for the internal device and switch the wireless back on:

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist iwl4965" >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
exit
```

Now turn the switch back to enable wireless, reboot and tell us if the USB is working.